# How to fix "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PngImageFile" error when keras calling numpy.asarray with dtype of float32

Tags: tf.keras

I am learning neuron network by building multilayer perceptron on a binary classification problem using `keras` with `tensorflow` as backend.

Here is the [source](https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/breast-histopathology-images) of image data.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11096) and [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10668).

From those issues I found, i think the error is related to `corrupted` image, but I tried those suggestion inside those links by verifying the image, the image have no problem for me but the error still persists.

The stacktrace shows that the error was occured when `keras` is trying to convert the image data to `numpy` array with data type of `float32`, so I tried converting the image to `numpy` array myself, and converting it like `numpy.asarray(image)` works but not `numpy.asarray(image, dtype='float32')` which was what `keras` was doing.

Assuming all `import` are in place.

So the code to data preparation

```
image_data_path = '../data/breast_histopathology'

image_width = 50
image_height = 50

train_size_as_percentage = 0.8
validate_size_percentage_of_train_data = 0.1

data_extract_path = image_data_path + '_prep'

train_data_path = data_extract_path + '/training'
test_data_path = data_extract_path + '/testing'
validation_data_path = data_extract_path + '/validation'

if os.path.isdir(data_extract_path):
    shutil.rmtree(data_extract_path)

os.makedirs(train_data_path)
os.makedirs(train_data_path + '/0')
os.makedirs(train_data_path + '/1')
os.makedirs(test_data_path)
os.makedirs(test_data_path + '/0')
os.makedirs(test_data_path + '/1')
os.makedirs(validation_data_path)
os.makedirs(validation_data_path + '/0')
os.makedirs(validation_data_path + '/1')

image_paths = [image_path for image_path in glob.glob(image_data_path + '/**/*', recursive=True)]

random.seed(128)
random.shuffle(image_paths)

training_size = int(len(image_paths) * train_size_as_percentage)
training_image_paths = image_paths[:training_size]
testing_image_paths = image_paths[training_size:]

validation_size = int(len(training_image_paths) * validate_size_percentage_of_train_data)
validation_image_paths = training_image_paths[:validation_size]
training_image_paths = training_image_paths[validation_size:]

datasets = [
    (train_data_path, training_image_paths),
    (test_data_path, testing_image_paths),
    (validation_data_path, validation_image_paths)
]

for data_path, image_paths in datasets:
    for image_path in image_paths:
        filename = image_path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        # filename would be, 10253_idx5_x1001_y1001_class0.png,
        # the character before . and word after class are the
        # labeling for the image
        class_label = filename[-5:-4]

        copy_destination = '{}/{}/{}'.format(data_path, class_label, filename)

        if os.path.isfile(image_path):            
            try:
                image = PIL.Image.open(image_path)
                image.verify()

#                 print('=============')
#                 print(filename)
#                 print(image_path)
#                 print(image)
#                 print(image.size)
#                 print(image.format)
#                 print(image.mode)
#                 print(image.verify())
#                 print(numpy.asarray(image, dtype='float32'))
#                 print('XXXXXXXXXXXXX')

                width, height = image.size

                if width == height == image_width and image.format == 'PNG':
                    shutil.copy2(image_path, copy_destination)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
                pass
```

Code to build and train the model

```
image_generator = keras_preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()

train_data_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_data_path,
    target_size=(image_width, image_height),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True)

validation_data_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=validation_data_path,
    target_size=(image_width, image_height),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True)

test_data_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=test_data_path,
    target_size=(image_width, image_height),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False)

input_layer = keras_layers.Input(shape=(image_width, image_height))

hidden_layer_output_neuron = int((image_width + 1) / 2)

hidden_layer_0 = keras_layers.Dense(
    units=hidden_layer_output_neuron,
    activation=keras.activations.relu,
    use_bias=True)(input_layer)

hidden_layer_1_output_unit = 16
hidden_layer_1 = keras_layers.Dense(
    units=hidden_layer_1_output_unit,
    activation=keras.activations.relu,
    use_bias=True)(hidden_layer_0)

hidden_layer_2_output_unit = 8
hidden_layer_2 = keras_layers.Dense(units=hidden_layer_2_output_unit, activation=keras.activations.relu, use_bias=True)(hidden_layer_1)

output_layer = keras_layers.Dense(
    units=1,
    activation=keras.activations.relu,
    use_bias=True)(hidden_layer_0)

learning_rate = 0.001

model = keras_models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras_optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate),
    loss=keras_losses.binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=[keras_metrics.Recall()])

model.fit_generator(
    generator=train_data_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_data_generator.n // train_data_generator.batch_size,
    validation_data=validation_data_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_data_generator.n // validation_data_generator.batch_size,
    epochs=100)
```

Expected result: No error

Actual result:

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-e2ffe31934fb> in <module>
      4     validation_data=validation_data_generator,
      5     validation_steps=validation_data_generator.n // validation_data_generator.batch_size,
----> 6     epochs=10)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1513         shuffle=shuffle,
   1514         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1515         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1516 
   1517   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    211     step = 0
    212     while step < target_steps:
--> 213       batch_data = _get_next_batch(generator, mode)
    214       if batch_data is None:
    215         if is_dataset:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in _get_next_batch(generator, mode)
    353   """Retrieves the next batch of input data."""
    354   try:
--> 355     generator_output = next(generator)
    356   except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    357     return None

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get(self)
    653     except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
    654       self.stop()
--> 655       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
    656 
    657 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get(self)
    647     try:
    648       while self.is_running():
--> 649         inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
    650         self.queue.task_done()
    651         if inputs is not None:

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    119         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    120         try:
--> 121             result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    122         except Exception as e:
    123             if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py in get_index(uid, i)
    443       The value at index `i`.
    444   """
--> 445   return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
    446 
    447 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     63         index_array = self.index_array[self.batch_size * idx:
     64                                        self.batch_size * (idx + 1)]
---> 65         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
     66 
     67     def __len__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    225                            target_size=self.target_size,
    226                            interpolation=self.interpolation)
--> 227             x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    228             # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,
    229             # but not PIL images.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py in img_to_array(img, data_format, dtype)
    280     # or (channel, height, width)
    281     # but original PIL image has format (width, height, channel)
--> 282     x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
    283     if len(x.shape) == 3:
    284         if data_format == 'channels_first':

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PngImageFile'
```